# How to write code so that Button is only clickable when condition is true?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

How can I write code in java so that when following IF Condition is true:

```
if (!online.equals(offline)){

}
```

Then only the

```
a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
**algorithm**
}
```

gets activated else the button stays unclickable.

NOTE: Both "online" and "offline" are String variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the enabled feature.  `myButton.setEnabled(false)` makes it unclickable, `myButton.setEnabled(true)` makes it clickable.  You can even use state list drawables to make disabled buttons look different.

Comment: Can you please show me how can I use :

`a1.setEnabled(false)`

and 

`a1.setEnabled(true)`

with 

`if (!online.equals(offline)){
}`

For:

`a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
**algorithm**
}`

Comment: I tried using it as:
`if (!online.equals(offline)){
a1.setEnabled(true);
a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { **algorithm** }
}
else if (online.equals(offline)){
a1.setEnabled(false);}`

But it crashes the app.

Comment: It worked, I used:
`if (!online.equals(offline)) 
{a1.setEnabled(true);}
                    else if(online.equals(offline))
                    {a1.setEnabled(false);}`